# What is DOM based templating?

Tags: angularjs, web-deployment

What is DOM based templating? I'm starting to learn AngularJS and I see the term many times. 
What are the advantages of DOM based templating?

Looking for something like the differences between String-based templates, how are the DOM based ones better, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> A DOM-based templating language relies on a DOM tree to recognize
> templating directives. A DOM-based templating will walk the DOM tree
> to discover templating directives and then manipulate the DOM tree to
> produce the final DOM tree that is then rendered in the browser. A
> DOM-based templating language only works in the browser unless a
> virtual DOM is used on the server. DOM-based templating languages are
> inherently much slower because the templates cannot be precompiled
> since the input is the DOM tree that is to be manipulated and the
> output is the manipulated DOM tree. In comparison, text-based and
> HTML-based templates can be precompiled into a JavaScript function
> that is a result of the compiler analyzing a template to find all of
> the interesting dynamic parts.
>
> Examples of DOM-based templating languages:
>
> AngularJS, Knockout, Weld

From Patrick Steele-Idem's link regarding JavaScript Templating Landscape http://psteeleidem.com/the-javascript-templating-landscape/ will help you to understand more detail about different JavaScript Templates.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in AngularJs you can specify templates in  tags and then label them to be used where ever you need them or you can create a template in an external html file and then use ng-include to include that template wherever you need it.

In a recent presentation the angular team stated that the future of angular would include shadow DOM and the ability to specify custom HTML tags and logic directly in the page without having to build a directive for your browser to understand what it is.